# "Avoir tellement envie de ... que ..." ou "avoir tellement d'envie de ... que ..."?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

Dans mon livre de grammaire, j'ai lu qu'on peut utiliser ces structures:

> **Tellement** + adjectif ou adverbe + **que** 
> Verbe + **tellement** +  **que** 
> Auxiliaire + **tellement** + participe passé + **que** 
> **Tellement de** + nom + **que**

Cependant, en cherchant sur Internet, j'ai trouvé de nombreux examples avec l'expression "avoir tellement envie de ... que ..." sans la préposition "de"  Sans la préposition "de" précédant le mot "envie". Par exemple,

> Nous avons tellement envie de les rencontrer que nous réussirions à devenir les gens les plus tolérants du monde.

Étant donné que "envie" est un nom, ne devrait-ce pas être "avoir tellement d'envie de ... que ..." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non, il ne faut pas ajouter « de » dans cette construction, la raison de cela étant que « avoir envie de » est une expression figée.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envie)) envie.

- Nous avons tellement envie de les rencontrer que nous réussirions à devenir les gens les plus tolérants du monde.

Si au lieu d'« avoir » le verbe « brûler » est utilisé, alors « de » devient nécessaire. Le sens est seulement plus fort, l'envie est plus forte.

- Nous brulons  tellement *d'envie* de les rencontrer que nous réussirions à devenir les gens les plus tolérants du monde.

On peut  utiliser une autre construction avec « avoir » (de même sens) et alors un article devient nécessaire.

- Nous avons *une* telle *envie* de les rencontrer que nous réussirions à devenir les gens les plus tolérants du monde.